# Arduino "avrdude" Error

Tags: arduino

I have been working with the Arduino system with an Arduino Uno chip for a while, but I recently came upon a problem I cannot solve. The problem is that whenever I attempt to upload a new program to my chip, I get the following error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

I have done some research, and I have tried everything that people have suggested. I have checked the COM port, checked the chip type, checked the component installations, updated the FTDI drivers, hit the reset button, tried the latest Arduino software, and yes, I have even made sure the board is plugged into the computer.

Earlier this year I had absolutely no problem uploading code to my board, and almost nothing has changed since I last tried it. The only thing that has changed is the cable I have used to upload the programs, and I have tried several different cables as well. Could it just be a batch of bad cables? This seems unlikely. I have also tried uploading code onto different boards, with the same result.

This is getting quite frustrating, as I really want to continue working on my projects. However, that will not happen if I cannot even print "Hello World!" to the serial monitor.
I am running on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine. Any suggestions to solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: Here is the diagnostic report in full                      Binary sketch size: 1,880 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
avrdude: can't open device "giveio"
avrdude: failed to open parallel port "lpt1"

Comment: Is your arduino connected to lpt1?  Try going to the serial port menu in the IDE.  Ensure you have selected the right device (probably a COM# port for windows) Also make sure that the correct board (Uno/Decimielia) is selected.

Comment: Yes, I have already done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the FTDI cable I was using. I tried a bunch of different cables until I found one that works, and now uploading occurs without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a normal upload using Serial then you should ensure your preferences are not set to "Upload using programmer" and that you are not selecting "Upload using programmer" from any of the Arduino menus.

EDIT

If you have not overridden the programmer then you must have the wrong board selected on the tools menu boards list. `lpt1` in the error message is not what the Uno uses.

Comment: Okay, I did this. Also, like I said in the original post, I HAVE checked the com port under the "Serial Port" menu, as well as the board type. I am still getting the original "not in sync" error.

Answer (score 0):

check the board you have selected in tools-> board . If you selected wrong board error comes as above. If right board being selected still getting same error , then it is definitely boot loader crashed error. You need to upload boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes parts connected to digital pin 0 and 1. The parts interfere communication between the computer and arduino so I recommend this procedure.

1. Check something is connected to D0 and D1.
2. If something is connected, unplug those.
3. Upload the sketch.
4. Plug parts removed at step 2.

Answer (score -1):

your arduino maybe not uno, change board to duemilanove.